# Make fails checking if directory exists

Tags: bash, makefile

I googled for this, but I can't figure out why Bash complains with the following code to check if a directory exists:

test.mk

```
#!/bin/bash

MYDIR="dl"
all:
        if [ ! -d $MYDIR ]; then
        #if [ ! -d "${MYDIR}" ]; then
        #if [ ! -d ${MYDIR} ]; then
                #Here
        fi
```

make -f test.mk

```
if [ ! -d YDIR ]; then
/bin/sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does someone know why it fails? And why does it call /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash? Thank you.

---

Edit: unlike Bash, make doesn't support multi-line block. Here's working code:

```
MYDIR="dl"
all:
        if [ ! -d ${MYDIR} ]; then\
                echo "Here";\
        else\
                echo "There";\
        fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#!/bin/bash` shebang that you inserted at top is useless, and it is treated by `make` as a comment.

`make` sends by default commands to `/bin/sh`. To specify a different shell, use the macro `SHELL = /bin/bash`.

Moreover, you need to escape your variable:

```
if [ ! -d ${MYDIR} ]
```

I'm not sure if `make` can handle multi-line statements, so try to put all the `if` block in a line.

```
if [ ! -d ${MYDIR} ]; then DO_SOMETHING; DO_SOMETHING_ELSE; fi
```

Comment: `make` handles multi-line statements just fine. Simply put a \ on the end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

You're feeding `test.mk` to `make`, not to `bash`. Then `make` sends individual lines to the shell, not whole blocks.

`make` uses its `SHELL` macro to determine which shell to use. You can override it to make it use `bash`.

The reason why you're getting `YDIR` is that `make` has silly rules about variable interpolation. Write `$(MYDIR)`, not `$MYDIR`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but not matter which format I use, ie. either $(MYDIR) or ${MYDIR}, sh still complains with "/bin/sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected"

Comment: @user try putting everything in one row as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try bracing your variable:

```
${MYDIR}
```